# Http authorization with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

My former server.js is like: 
After running the server I could see my index.html

```
var connect = require('connect');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
connect().use(serveStatic(__dirname)).listen(5000, '192.168.xx.xx', function(){
    console.log('Server running on 5000');
});
```

I want to create http login and password to secure the website, so I found online the information of http module: if I put right login and password, I could see congratulations message:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        // console.log(req);   // debug dump the request

        // If they pass in a basic auth credential it'll be in a header called "Authorization" (note NodeJS lowercases the names of headers in its request object)

        var auth = req.headers['authorization'];  // auth is in base64(username:password)  so we need to decode the base64
        console.log("Authorization Header is: ", auth);

        if(!auth) {     // No Authorization header was passed in so it's the first time the browser hit us

                // Sending a 401 will require authentication, we need to send the 'WWW-Authenticate' to tell them the sort of authentication to use
                // Basic auth is quite literally the easiest and least secure, it simply gives back  base64( username + ":" + password ) from the browser
                res.statusCode = 401;
                res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="Secure Area"');

                res.end('<html><body>Need authorization</body></html>');
        }

        else if(auth) {    // The Authorization was passed in so now we validate it

                var tmp = auth.split(' ');   // Split on a space, the original auth looks like  "Basic Y2hhcmxlczoxMjM0NQ==" and we need the 2nd part

                var buf = new Buffer(tmp[1], 'base64'); // create a buffer and tell it the data coming in is base64
                var plain_auth = buf.toString();        // read it back out as a string

                console.log("Decoded Authorization ", plain_auth);

                // At this point plain_auth = "username:password"

                var creds = plain_auth.split(':');      // split on a ':'
                var username = creds[0];
                var password = creds[1];

                if((username == 'admin') && (password == 'admin')) {   // Is the username/password correct?

                        res.statusCode = 200;  // OK
                        res.end('<html><body>Congratulations, feel free to explre!</body></html>');
                }
                else {
                        res.statusCode = 401; // Force them to retry authentication
                        res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="Secure Area"');

                        // res.statusCode = 403;   // or alternatively just reject them altogether with a 403 Forbidden

                        res.end('<html><body>You shall not pass</body></html>');
                }
        }
});


server.listen(5000, function() { console.log("Server Listening on http://localhost:5000/"); });
```

I am new to nodejs, I want to know how to combine this 2 js? In order to realize my function of adding authorization to my web. 
Could I do something to show my index instead of showing congratulation message after putting the login and password?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show HTML page instead of congratulation message, you can follow these steps:

1. Get request path by `req.url`, such as `/` or `/introduction.html`.
2. According to the above path, read the corresponding HTML file in server disk, using `fs.readFile()`.
3. Return HTML file content to browser if the read is successful. Otherwise, return `404` error page.

Here is some example code for above steps:

```
if((username == 'admin') && (password == 'admin')) {   // Is the username/password correct?

  res.statusCode = 200;  // OK
  // res.end('<html><body>Congratulations, feel free to explre!</body></html>');
  var requestURL = req.url; // e.g. / or /a or /a.html
  var requestFilePath = getFilePathFromRequestURL(requestURL); // you need to implement this logic yourself, such as "/" mapping to "./index.html"
  fs.readFile(requestFilePath, function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
      res.statusCode = 404;
      res.write('File not found.');
    } else {
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.write(data);
    }
    res.end();
  });
}
```

However, unless you want to write some low-level node.js code to better understand this language, I highly recommend using node.js web framework such as Express. Serve HTTP request using low-level node.js would be tedious, especially in production code.

Also, please note that using `WWW-Authenticate Basic` for authentication is neither secure nor user-friendly. You need some other way to implement authentication, such as [JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I chose to use express with basic-auth, it's lighter and easier.